# Specifying relationship on both nodes results in a logical cyclic mapping dependency in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-neo4j

I have a use-case where I need to specify a relationship in two node classes, one as ingoing and one as outgoing. This was working in SDN 6.0.2, but is failing when trying to update to 6.1.5. I have a base class and two custom classes defined as

```
abstract class Base(
    @DateLong @CreatedDate @LastModifiedDate var updated: Date? = null,
    @CreatedBy @LastModifiedBy var source: String? = null,
) {
    abstract val customId: String
}

@Node
data class Foo(
    @Id override val customId: String,
    val name: String,
    @Relationship(
        type = "CONFIGURED_TO",
        direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING
    ) var bars: Set<Bar> = emptySet(),
) : Base()

@Node
data class Bar(
    @Id override val customId: String,
    val name: String,
    @Relationship(
        type = "CONFIGURED_TO",
        direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING
    ) var foos: Set<Foo> = emptySet(),

) : Base()
```

When performing queries using the recent SDN updates this relationship defined in both Node classes results in `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: The node with id 10 has a logical cyclic mapping dependency. Its creation caused the creation of another node that has a reference to this.`

I don't need to fetch `Foo` nodes when fetching `Bar`, but defining the relationship is on both required for simpler implementation when updating the relationships. Is there a way to not fetch the nodes when using the Spring Data Neo4j derived queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background:
The truth is that it was also not working 100% correct in 6.0(.2).
SDN was creating not only one but two instances if `Foo` or `Bar` to resolve the cycle of constructor dependencies (defined by the data classes).
Of course this behavior was not intended.

To not fetch the `Foo` nodes when fetching `Bar` you should use projections: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

e.g. (in Java)

```
interface BarProjection {
   String getName();
}
```

and in the repository

```
interface BarRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Bar, String> {
   BarProjection findByName(String name);
}
```

**!** But this would not save you from cleaning up the cyclic defined dependency that leads to the chicken/egg-problem in the data classes.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. In my use-case it was clearly simpler to just rewrite a bit of the service logic after dropping the relationship in one of the nodes than using projections, but good to know that's possible too.